# For loop model Simulink

Tags: matlab, for-loop, model, simulink, factorial

I want to model a *for loop system* in *Simulink*, how I can model the following *MATLAB* syntax into *Simulink* model?

```
N=3;
    for    i=0:1:N
    sum(i+1)=factorial(i)/factorial(N);  
    end
```

I have tried for loop sub systems in *Simulink* and also *Sum block* for iteration loop but doesn't help me. *factorial* function can be calculated with *FCN* function.
Suggest me the ways to resolve this model with step time.

Comment: I suggest you change (in Matlab) `factorial(i)/facrorial(N)` to `1/prod(i+1:N)`. That will save computations an avoid overflow (if `N` is large). Also, it's best [not to use `i` as a variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: OK, it seems very efficient way, how can I save the computations if I have, factorial(N)/(factorial(i)*factorial(N-i)) ? Also, how can i avoid imaginary unit that gives efficiency?

Comment: Replace `for i=` by `for ii=`; and replace `factorial(N)/(factorial(i)*factorial(N-i))` by `prod((N-ii+1:N)./[1:ii])`

Comment: sum(ii+1) remains there? does it affects the performance?

Comment: @LuisMendo it gives following error:
Computed maximum size of the output of function 'colon' is not bounded.
Static memory allocation requires all sizes to be bounded.
The computed size is [1 x :?].

Comment: This can be done quite easily using a MATLAB function block, but since the number of elements in the output is dependent on the value of N (which I assume is not really hard coded a 3, but rather can change during a simulation) you'll need to use variable sized signals.  Search the doc for that term to learn how to define them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the code already in matlab use a embedded matlab function to implement it i your simulink model. This is in general quite efficient since it will be compiled (compared to interpreted matlab function blocks)